# Sequence which does not admit weakly convergent subsequences

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

*Let $f_h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f_h(x)=h$ if $0\le x\le 1$ and $f_h(x)=0$ otherwise. Prove that it does not exist a subsequence $(f_{h_k})_k$ weakly convergent in $L^1(0,1)$.*

**Attempt of solution**. Let's proceed by contraposition. I have to find a functional $\Phi\in(L^1(0,1))'$ such that $<\Phi,f_{h_k}>$ does not converge (in $\mathbb{R}$) to $<\Phi,f>$. By Riesz's Representation theorem, I can "represent" the elements of $(L^1(0,1))'$ through functions in $L^{\infty}(0,1)$.

$1)$If I find $g\in L^{\infty}(0,1)$ such that $\int_0^1f_{h_k}gdx$ does not converge to $\int_0^1fgdx$ I am done.

**My doubt is**: our professor suggested us to look for a sequence $(g_i)_i\in L^{\infty}(0,1)$ such that $lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1f_{h_k}g_idx=1$ for every $i$ fixed and $lim_{i\to\infty}\int_0^1fg_idx=0$.

I can't understand why this hint is equivalent to $1)$

Comment: What does the notation $(f_{h_k})_k$ mean? And what is $h_k$? What is $f$?

Comment: the first one is an arbitrary subsequence of $(f_h)_h$. The latter is its limit in $L^1$

Comment: Thanks. But if $h_k \to g\in \mathbb R$, then $f_{h_k}$ converges strongly to $f_g$ in $L^1$.

Comment: @avati91 John is right. Perhaps $h_k$ is required to go to $\infty$? But in this case, the result is clear by Banach-Steinhaus because $(f_{h_k})$ is not bounded in $L^1$.

Comment: @avati91 Something else: the domain of definition of $f_h$ is most likely not $[0,1]$ (have a look at your definition).